# Why is a part from a Boeing 777 being analysed by Airbus?

Tags: mh370-incident

Since [MH370](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370) was a [Boeing 777](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370), why are they taking the suspected wing flaperon to [Toulouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toulouse), France?

Are some spare parts made by Airbus?

Comment: Is it confirmed that the wing was from MH370?

Comment: @Firee Even the accident investigators with normally cautious press interaction are not really doing much to cut down on speculation...

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot: Could it be a discarded wing of an old 777 tossed into the sea, or fell from a ship

Comment: @Firee "old" 777 ?!?

Comment: `Why is part from B777 being analysed by Airbus` Who said that it is?

Comment: @Federico: I meant, the 777 in service today which might be older, and might have required a change of flaperon

Comment: @Simon: I think MikeFoxtrot has mentioned a source in his answer below

Comment: @Firee I've read the whole thing and I must be missing something.  Nowhere can I see mention of Airbus being involved.

Comment: I think some people are just confused since they associate 'Toulouse' very strongly with Airbus...

Comment: @Firee [It is now](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-33794012).

Comment: I've put the term _flaperon_ to Goole Translate and it said it was not English but Esperanto. Just saying.

Comment: @Firee it was confirmed that the part was from a 777, and since no 777's other than MH370 have gone missing, it would have to be a pretty interesting circumstance to not be from MH370.

Comment: Downvoted for false and baseless premise! Toulouse is a city, not a single building for a single company. You know what _assuming_ does...

Answer (score 70):

> Why are they taking the wing to Toulouse, FR?

Because the part was found on the island of [Réunion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9union), which is French territory.

> Why is a part from a B777 being analysed by Airbus?

**It is not**. Airbus is not the only company/institution to have plants/facilities in Toulouse: [The BEA](http://www.bea.aero/en/) (France's equivalent to the NTSB) also has facilities there.

Comment: There is a lot of aerospace activity in Toulouse. The French space agency, [CNES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNES), operates out of Toulouse - *[Toulouse Space Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toulouse_Space_Center)*.

Answer (score 39):

To extend a bit on Federico's answer. As I understand, [BEA](http://www.bea.aero/en/), the French accident authority, have some office in Toulouse while the facility itself where it will be looked at is military.

> France's BEA crash investigation agency will examine the wing flap at the Direction Generale de l'Armement compound near Toulouse. [Source](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2015/07/31/world/mh370-trail-now-leads-france-investigators-will-probe-plane-debris/)

Also from the BEA website, under the heading ICAO:

> In particular, **States must start an investigation in case of a civil aviation accident or serious incident on their territory.** It is specified that "The sole objective of the investigation of an accident or incident shall be the prevention of accidents and incidents" and that "It is not the purpose of this activity to apportion blame or liability".
>
> Close association between the representatives of the States of Registry, Operation, Design and Manufacture of the aircraft is organised. This brings to the State that is leading the investigation useful skills and information and allows for feedback that is as fast and complete as possible in terms of safety. [Source](http://www.bea.aero/en/bea/qui-sommes-nous/cadre-juridique.php)

Which explains their responsibility in investigating the part. I don't think there are too many facilities with extensive knowledge of forensic engineering on impact-damaged (composite) parts (Even analysis of damaged Black Boxes is often 'outsourced') so they might even be happy to have the large BEA look at it.

---

The French are not unfamiliar with investigating aircraft accidents and have participated in a few substantial ones in the last few years. I discovered presumably the [same folks](http://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/wreckage-of-af447-transferred-as-recovery-effort-ends-357850/) were involved in forensic engineering work of the [AF447](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_447) remains in 2011, which also crashed into the ocean.

> French investigation agency Bureau d'Enquetes et d'Analyses said the vessel would transfer to Bayonne, a port on the south-western coast, and parts from flight AF447 would be moved to a hangar in Toulouse.
>
> The wreckage would be examined by the French defence ministry's technical aeronautical division. The recovery effort also retrieved several victims of the crash and these will be taken for forensic assessment.

Footnote: Since accidents with unclear events (or presenting controversial claims like crashing the plane) such as this one which can be a hot potato it is sometimes even desired to have a independent third party look at the stuff.

Comment: It is also perhaps worth noting that Boeings have long been used by French companies (notably B737, 747, 777 and now 787 by Air France), in much the same way Airbus aircraft have been used in the States. I am also sure many Airbus engineers are current on their competitor's offerings, if only to better counter them. So I wouldn't be surprised there is actually quite a lot of knowledge about Boeings in the aircraft sector in Toulouse. BEA will have a large pool of potential consultants to draw on if necessary.